# Throwing an exception if, for example, int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE-1;

Tags: exception, overflow, underflow

Do you know of any languages which would throw an Exception on Overflow or Underflow?
Thanks

Comment: Plenty - you might want to make your question a tad more specific.  Is this for the .Net framework?

Comment: The original purpose of the question was to find out how many languages do support it, so the question was not specific by design.

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework has a dedicated exception for Overflow

[OverflowException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can let underflow and overflow throw exceptions using the [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword:

```
int a = checked(Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1);
```